# How to debug "Windows were created before application initialzation completed."

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

My universal iOS app displays the message

> [ApplicationLifecycle] Windows were created before application
>   initialzation completed. This may result in incorrect visual
>   appearance.

Right at the start of launch - before didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is reached. The app does not crash although there is an issue later where a screen is unexpectedly blank - not sure why.
The app does not display this message on an iPhone.
The iPad uses a splitviewcontroller (actually a custom one).

It is written in objective-C with a mainWindow.xib, as opposed to storyboard.
Can anyway offer any suggestions as to how to determine what is causing this issue.

Comment: If you have any code that creates window in `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, try moving that to `didFinishLaunching` in your `AppDelegate`

Comment: Thanks but I don't call willFinishLaunchingWithOptions in this app.

Comment: Can you please share your code of AppDelegate class ?

Comment: Can't believe Apple spelled it "initialzation"… makes it easier to search for though!

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, the error will show only on ipad size 10.5 or bigger, i don't know if this will help you, in my case was caused by the launchImage. To solved I changed in settings - target - general, in the field - Launch screen file - set it to = LaunchScreen, and then in  I dragged an image view on LaunchScreen.storyboard and load a LaunchImage.png  in the image field.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to PabloT.'s answer:

In your target settings, look for `General` - `App Icons and Launch Images` and see if the `Launch Screen File` is blank. You should set it to your `mainWindow.xib`.

This will not only solve this issue, it will also help to adjust your app to bigger iPad screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me: You have to keep a reference to `UIWindow`, because when returning from `didFinishLaunching`, the temporary `UIWindow *window` is lost.
This means:

```
@interface AppDelegate ()
{
    UIWindow *myWindow;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I stopped receiving this error when I deleted the `Launch Screen.xib` left over from my Swift conversion.

The original app was in Objective-C, which required the `xib` file. After completing conversion recently, I started receiving the subject error message.

I deleted the `Launch Code.xib`, cleaned everything, and rebuilt. I haven't received the error since.